# R, keras: How to get output of a hidden layer?

Tags: neural-network, r, keras

I am using package `Keras` in R to do a neural network. How may I extract the output from a hidden layer? I found an [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/588) in python, but it is just I have no idea how to do that in R.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to do this? Are you looking to do something with the weights?

Comment: @I_Play_With_Data This is particularly useful when you train an auto-encoder and you want to extract the last layer of the encoder for dimensionality reduction.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the answer [here](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/faq.html).

Here it is:

```
model <- ...  # create the original model
layer_name <- 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model <- keras_model(inputs = model$input,
                                    outputs = get_layer(model, layer_name)$output)
intermediate_output <- predict(intermediate_layer_model, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as this account is new, so I'll post this as an additional answer:
When using `get_layer()` using `index = ...` instead of `layer_name = ...`, it should be noted that there is a discrepancy between using it as written by Perochkin and using it in the python-style of `model$get_layer(...)`:

```
model$get_layer(index = as.integer(5))
```

returns the layer on the zero-based layer index,  while

```
get_layer(model, index = as.integer(5))
```

or

```
model %>% get_layer(index = as.integer(5))
```

is 1-based, so these return different layers. I didn't find this information anywhere else, so I wanted to share, as this cost me quite some time to find out